# How is a Game Manager supposed to be constructed?

Tags: unity, game-design

I'm a beginner developing games on Unity3D and now that I've become a little bit familiar with `GameManagers` I've been wondering about certain aspects.

How do you contruct a `GameManager` in the most efficient way? Since it's an entity that persists through scene loads, it has to be tweaked to reset some values on level load because it doesn't do that by itself.

I'm making a 2D platformer, so when a new level is loaded (or the current level is restarted) the `GameManager` has to dynamically find references to the objects it handles. And because each level cannot be identical to the next, should I have code in the `GameManager` to find references to the specific `GameObjects` and values depending on the level? I'm thinking something like this:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

  //Values and core methods etc

  void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) {
    if (level == 1) {
      //Find references and set values for level 1
    }
    if (level == 2) {
      //Find references and set values for level 2
    }
  }
}
```

Or should I have a separate `GameManager` for values, game states and events and an in-between script for handling the `GameObject` references? I just want to learn this right. I'm worrying that if I dump "everything" in the `GameManager`, it becomes too big and inefficient.

Speaking of which, is it OK for the `GameManager` to also handle the UI/HUD? Or should there be a separate `UIManager` dedicated for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI and HUD is better managed elsewhere. the `GameManager` is supposed to manage the game state and transitions between game states and nothing else. Possible states could be `title`, `menu`, `loading` or `ingame`. Note that there are *not* states for every level like `levelXY`.

See the scene/level as the data for a state. You might come into a situation where need to specialise for certain levels like having state for `carchase` or `indoor`. You will have a persistent game object that holds the `GameManager` and other managers. Keep in mind that it must be a singleton or you will end up with multiple `GameManagers`.

Additional managers could handle music so you could have music playing during game state transitions.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the advice! I must have misunderstood the concept. So basically there needs to be a separate level manager? And that it's altogether more efficient to have separate managers for all things that need managing.

Comment: @yotara Depends on the complexity of your levels or game. It may be sufficent if every level by itself knows what level comes next. Information what level comes next could also be data in doors or exits. There might be no need for a level manager.